# Syntax error in configuration file - future feature unicode_literals is not defined (Python,Django,Sphinx)

Tags: python, django, windows, python-sphinx, easy-install

I'm trying out Django.
I was going to read it's documentation.
It wasn't there, I had to build it. Read the `Readme` in `Django-1.5/doc` folder, downloaded the Sphinx documentation Python module.
Installed it using easy_install - that got installed to Python2.5
Doesn't matter. Just have to generate docs, can use Py2.5.
I do that, `make html` in the `/doc` folder, and I get this:

```
Running Sphinx v1.1.3

Configuration error:
There is a syntax error in your configuration file: future feature unicode_literals is not defined (conf.py, line 14)
```

The conf.py is the file in the Django-1.5/doc folder. Line 14 is this:

`from __future__ import unicode_literals`

I searched why, and on some page I saw that support for 2.5 was dropped for **future** or I don't know what I couldn't understand really.
So I `easy_install`ed Sphinx to Python 2.7 then, hoping that would solve version stuff.

Then I do `make html` again, in the /doc folder of Django, and I get the same build error as stated above. 
How can I make the `make` command do the making from the Python 2.7 installed Sphinx version?

I just want to generate the damn docs.
I love Python and everything, but all these installations of packages are a pain on Windows.

Comment: I feel your pain, or at least I did until I installed ubuntu and then all my pains went away.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx generate documentation, a part of it is made from source code which can be target of introspection/partial execution.

As `__future__` is not a module (can't "import" it except if it's first instruction).

So I'm don't think it answer your question but it's logical and a good thing as it's a way to support python 3k and discourage usage of unmaintained old releases of Python[1].

you're lucky some nice peoples already compiled the documentation for you:

Here up to date trunk documentation:
http://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/latest/django.pdf

And here the 1.5 release's pdf:
http://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/1.5.x/django.pdf

If you wanted the html version, you'll have to use an offline reader: http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.x/

Hope it solves your problem even if it doesn't answer your question.

I suppose your production environment will NOT be windows. Most windows attached django's developpers will use cygwin or a virtual machine to work. Django and python offers awesome CLI tools. Those CLI tools can't be awesome if you live in the CLI's hell.

note: CLI -> Command Line Interface.

1. http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.5.6/ : >  **under the current release policy, no security issues in Python 2.5 will be fixed anymore.**

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.5 doesn't accept `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. Type `help("__future__")` at Python prompt, to see the docs.

> How can I make the make command do the making from the Python 2.7 installed Sphinx version?

You could try to specify PYTHON option e.g., in bash:

```
$ PYTHON=python2.7 make html
```

On Windows it is probably:

```
T:\> set PYTHON=C:\path\to\Python27\python.exe
T:\> make html
```

You could use `setx` to set the variable permanently.

---

You don't need to build documentation to try out Django. It is available [online](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/) or you could download it using [links provided by @christophe31](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364865/4279).

[Django 1.5 dropped support for Python 2.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#python-compatibility).

Comment: I know I don't "need" to build documentation. I was just hell bent on making it, rather say, why the hell all that documentation making shiz wasn't working on my setup.

Comment: And yeah. I did the `set` thing, set it to Python 2.7, but still got that error.

Is there anyway I can know which version of Python is the `make` command working for? I'm guessing it's still working for Python 2.5 if it's spewing out that same stuff.